# MySQL delete rows that have parameter which refers to the not exist ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database, exists

I need to remove from the table all records that have the "for_id" parameter refers to the "id" that is not present in this table.

[In this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f523d5/1), I need to delete the row with `name` =" tom " since the entries with `id` = 3 do not exist.

Thanks!

Comment: Edit your post and add the database you use to the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE D.* FROM table_name D
  LEFT JOIN table_name T
    ON T.ID=D.FOR_ID
 WHERE T.ID IS NULL and D.FOR_ID<>0;
```

test on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a2fed/1)

Comment: You're genius! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

So you want to `remove` those records for which `for_id` does `not exist` in the `id`
In other words, `keep`  those records for which `for_id` does `exists` in the `id`

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
where for_id in (select id from table_name)
```

or using `join`:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM 
table_name t1 join table_name t2
on t1.for_id=t2.id
```

Output:

```
| id | for_id | lvl | name |
|----|--------|-----|------|
|  4 |      1 |   1 |  joe |
|  5 |      1 |   1 | mack |
|  6 |      5 |   2 | bill |
|  7 |      5 |   2 |  rex |
|  8 |      7 |   3 |  ted |
```

Comment: NO!!! I need to REMOVE all records that have the "for_id" parameter refers to the "id" that is not exist in this table.

Comment: Okay So you want to `KEEP` all records the have the "for_id" parameter which refers to the "id" that `exists` in this table ? If yes, check the updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the ones that have for_id=0 too then you can use:

```
DELETE 
FROM table_name as t1
where not exists (select id 
       from table_name as t2 
       where t2.id=t1.for_id)
```

and if you don't want to delete the ones that have for_id=0 you can use:

```
delete 
FROM table_name as t1
where not exists (select id 
       from table_name as t2 
       where t2.id=t1.for_id) and t1.for_id<>0
```

Comment: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as t1 where not exists (select id from categories as t2 where t2.id=t1.for_id) a' at line 1' if I try execute 2-nd script.

Comment: Try to **encapsulate your field & table names in backticks (`)** for using the query with PDO

Comment: I'm pardon but I know it. I had tried many variants of $del_sub_cat=$dbh->query("DELETE FROM `categories` as t1 where not exists (select `id` from `categories` as t2 where t2.id=t1.for_id) and t1.for_id<>0");  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as t1 where not exists (select `id` from `categories` as t2 where t2.id=t1.for_i' at line 1'